# Сайт "заезжает справо на лево" во время загрузки. Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, css

Сайт "заезжает справо на лево" во время загрузки. Как исправить?

Видимо мешают ссылки меню, пока они не сворачиваются JavaScript'ом. При этом грузиться большое количество стилей и скриптов JS, как лучше решить такую проблему?

Скиншоты ниже:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Без кода нельзя ничего сказать. Что именно сворачивается в меню? Где расположено подключение стилей и скриптов? И будет лучше объединить их в несколько файлов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавил html -  и проблема решена!